# How can I handle the exception "cannot call method getRange of null" in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, exception, extjs, null, runtime-error

I've searched the net for answer but didn't find anything. Hope you can help.
So I am relativly new to `extJs`. I have a navigation bar on the left. When I press the first button there, a new window opens, which contains a table and loads its data automatically. The first time it works perfect but when I close the window and open it again I get the error "cannot call method getRange of null".

If I open the second window (when I click the other button in my navigation bar), I have 4 tabs, which contain a table each. Each Tab has a toolbar with buttons (create, change, etc.). Here happens the same thing as by the first window. 
I can also print those tables as a List and the first time works fine, but when I cancel the print action I get the error again.

I made sure that all buttons and tables have a different reference, so I really don't know what this could be.

Any ideas?

I add my panels, which will open the new windows here:

```
items: [
        {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            region: 'center',
            items: [{
                // 1. Tab
                xtype: 'componentTap-panel',
                title: UMA.Locale.rm.component.componentTitle,
                id: 'componentTab'
            }, {
                // 2. Tab
                title: UMA.Locale.rm.componentGroup.componentGroupTitle,
                xtype: 'componentGroupTap-panel',
                id: 'componentGroupTab'
            }, {
                // 3. Tab
                title: UMA.Locale.rm.componentTemplateTitle,
                xtype: 'componentTamplate-panel',
                id: 'componentTemplateTab'
            },
            {
                //4.Tab
                title: UMA.Locale.rm.inventoryTitle,
                xtype: 'inventoryTab-panel',
                id: 'inventoryTab'
            }
            ]
        }

]
```

When the window opens I add my table and toolbar:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    region: 'north',
    reference: 'componentToolbar',
    items: [{
        text: UMA.Locale.rm.buttonCreate,
        action: 'createComp'
    }, {
            text: UMA.Locale.rm.buttonChange,
            action: 'changeComp'
        }, {
            text: UMA.Locale.rm.buttonMove,
            action: 'moveComp'
        }, {
            text: UMA.Locale.rm.buttonDelete,
            action: 'deleteComp'
        },{
            text: UMA.Locale.rm.buttonPrint,
            action: 'print',
            margin: {
                left: 8

}, {
        xtype: 'componentTable-panel',
        region: 'center'
    }, {
        xtype: 'componentsFilter-panel',
        width: 300,
        region: 'east'
    }]
```

and then autoload my table:

```
items:[{
    xtype: 'filtergrid',
    reference: 'componentGrid',
    paging: true,
    hideHeaders: false,
        region: 'center',
        selModel: new Ext.selection.RowModel({
                mode: "MULTI"
        }),

        store: {
            model: 'Component',
            autoLoad: true
        },

        columns: [{ ...
```

Comment: Since `getRange()` is a store method (as I understand from your question) somewhere in your button handlers you manipulating with store instance and its reference variable contains `null`. So try to `console.log` store in your handlers. If you provide some code (fiddle with this error would be very helpfull) we can provide more specific solution.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov added some code, hope you understand

Comment: It will be very difficult to help you like this, can you at least create a fiddle (fiddle.sencha.com) that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Object()` constructor to test whether the object is one of three subtypes:

- null object
- object object
- array object

For example:

```js
function foo() { return {"hi":"bye" } }
function bar() { return null }
function baz() { return [1,2,3] }

function testObject(myObject)
  {
  if (Object(myObject).hasOwnProperty("0") )
    {
    /* Call getRange */
    return 'yes';
    }
  else
    {
    /* throw an exception */
    return 'no';
    }
  }

console.log(testObject(foo()), testObject(bar()), testObject(baz()) );
```

Answer (score 3):

As Sergey Novikov mentioned that `getRange()` is a store method.
I also faced the same error for my grid's store and after some review again and again I found that whenever I close the tab and reopen it again I am getting two instance of grid's view (which can be checked by `grid.getView()`) and then I reached a conclusion that whenever the grid is creating the second time the selection model of grid view is having two instances because of I am using the code for `selModel` as `new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel({
    showHeaderCheckbox: true,
    width: 50,
    mode: 'MULTI'
})`

then I changed the code for `selModel` as

`selModel: {
    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    showHeaderCheckbox: true,
    width: 50,
    mode: 'MULTI'
  }`

and the error is gone for me.
Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: You saved me several days of debugging and major problems with my boss.